# Answer or solution to an exercise?

Tags: word-choice, nouns, synonyms

In the context of the word *exercise*, e.g. in a textbook, is it more common to say *answer* or *solution*?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It would depend what the exercise was; if it is a question such as "What is the capital of Mongolia?", the response is an *answer*. If the question were something like "find the length of the hypotenuse of this triangle", you could use either word; the workings would be part of the *solution* but not part of the *answer*.

I'd also suggest that an incorrect response to either question could be called an *answer*, but wouldn't be a *solution*.

Answer (score 1):

**Answer** is the word you are looking for.

My dictionary says:

> **Answer** • a thing written or said in reaction to a question in a test or quiz : *write your answers on a postcard.*

Like the definition says, it is what you say in response to the exercise's question, being it an actual question or a fill-in-the-gap type, such as:

> Mary ***_*__*_*_** (go) to the Mall yesterday.

Your answer would be "**went**" in this case.

What you call *solution* reminds me of the `solutions section` at the end of the Textbook, but it is rather called **Key** than "solution".

Plus solution meant as "answer" is too general, since solution can be the "answer" to a problem and not just to an exercise.

Answer (score 1):

Interesting question.

Your choice of 'answer' or 'solution' would lie in what the exercise was.

The verb for exercise would most likely be 'complete' or simply do.

'Answer' would be used with a question and
'solution' with a problem.

Answer the question. -or- Provide an answer to the question.
Solve the problem. -or- provide a solution to the problem.